# Difference in attribute datatypes and values when reading the same file using read.csv and read.csv2

Tags: r

I am seeing a difference in the datatype and values of the attributes when using read.csv and read.csv2 to read the same file.

When I use read.csv :

```
mainData <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-white.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

The structure of the dataframe "mainData" is as shown below:

```
'data.frame':   4898 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ fixed.acidity       : num  7 6.3 8.1 7.2 7.2 8.1 6.2 7 6.3 8.1 ...
 $ volatile.acidity    : num  0.27 0.3 0.28 0.23 0.23 0.28 0.32 0.27 0.3 0.22 ...
 $ citric.acid         : num  0.36 0.34 0.4 0.32 0.32 0.4 0.16 0.36 0.34 0.43 ...
 $ residual.sugar      : num  20.7 1.6 6.9 8.5 8.5 6.9 7 20.7 1.6 1.5 ...
 $ chlorides           : num  0.045 0.049 0.05 0.058 0.058 0.05 0.045 0.045 0.049 0.044 ...
 $ free.sulfur.dioxide : num  45 14 30 47 47 30 30 45 14 28 ...
 $ total.sulfur.dioxide: num  170 132 97 186 186 97 136 170 132 129 ...
 $ density             : num  1.001 0.994 0.995 0.996 0.996 ...
 $ pH                  : num  3 3.3 3.26 3.19 3.19 3.26 3.18 3 3.3 3.22 ...
 $ sulphates           : num  0.45 0.49 0.44 0.4 0.4 0.44 0.47 0.45 0.49 0.45 ...
 $ alcohol             : num  8.8 9.5 10.1 9.9 9.9 10.1 9.6 8.8 9.5 11 ...
 $ quality             : int  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
```

On the other hand, when I use read.csv2, I get a different result:

```
mainData <- read.csv2("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-white.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

In this case, all the independent attributes are read as factors and their values are also different:

```
'data.frame':   4898 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ fixed.acidity       : Factor w/ 68 levels "10","10.2","10.3",..: 38 30 50 41 41 50 29 38 30 50 ...
 $ volatile.acidity    : Factor w/ 125 levels "0.08","0.085",..: 37 43 39 29 29 39 47 37 43 27 ...
 $ citric.acid         : Factor w/ 87 levels "0","0.01","0.02",..: 37 35 41 33 33 41 17 37 35 44 ...
 $ residual.sugar      : Factor w/ 310 levels "0.6","0.7","0.8",..: 190 18 258 286 286 258 261 190 18 16 ...
 $ chlorides           : Factor w/ 160 levels "0.009","0.012",..: 35 39 40 48 48 40 35 35 39 34 ...
 $ free.sulfur.dioxide : Factor w/ 132 levels "10","101","105",..: 66 17 41 68 68 41 41 66 17 36 ...
 $ total.sulfur.dioxide: Factor w/ 251 levels "10","100","101",..: 76 36 249 94 94 249 40 76 36 32 ...
 $ density             : Factor w/ 890 levels "0.98711","0.98713",..: 879 472 561 602 602 561 545 879 472 454 ...
 $ pH                  : Factor w/ 103 levels "2.72","2.74",..: 24 54 50 43 43 50 42 24 54 46 ...
 $ sulphates           : Factor w/ 79 levels "0.22","0.23",..: 23 27 22 18 18 22 25 23 27 23 ...
 $ alcohol             : Factor w/ 104 levels "10","10.0333333333333",..: 88 95 3 104 104 3 98 88 95 22 ...
 $ quality             : int  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
```

Why is this the case? Aren't read.csv and read.csv2 practically the same?

Also, why aren't the datatype and values of the dependent variable (mainData$quantity) affected similarly?

Finally, what are the best practices when reading data from a URL? Thanks!

Comment: the data aren't even the same between the two functions, so R's guess for typing are different too. csv2 is designed for locals that use "," for a decimal in number notation. Look at the `dec` argument. Quality isn't effected bc it is whole numbers, with no decimals to parse. I suggest `read.table(sep = ";")` instead of either csv version

Comment: You are absolutely right, `read.csv` and `read.csv2` are *practically* the same, but in `read.csv` argument `dec = "."` and in `read.csv2` it is `dec = ","`. I live in continental Europe where the decimals are marked with a comma and that error is so frequent you wouldn't imagine.

Comment: Copied from the first line of the second `str` output: `levels "10","10.2","10.3"`. This gives away that `"10.2"` was read in as a string, converted to factor, not as a number.

Comment: @Nate The data *are* the same, their display is different because the numbers and factors are ordered differently.

Comment: Not really because of the `dec` argument, sure the underlying csv values are identical, but my point was once `read.csv/read.csv2` touch them the values/data in R's view diverge and become different types. But I can see your point that you could coherce columns back to be equivalent types